# Image Function adding Implicit intersection At operator Image Function not working

Tags: xml, excel-formula, caxlsx

When Excel opens an XML file created by Caxlsx an @ sign is being added to the Image formula.

We believe this is due to the following upgrade in Excel's formula language,  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34

The Image function should not be treated as an Array, but we even coded the Image function as an array, we  still are having problems with Excel executing the Image Forumula without an explicit command.

I have attached our manual work around that loads the images via the video in column H.

Any help to find an automated solution would be appreciated, the solution **cannot** include VB\Macro.

Manual work around training - https://contenthub.kraftheinz.com/api/public/content/03197901aa5b4b71a6f803890921a3be?v=8c65bb81

File Link See Column H https://urldefense.com/v3/__https://salsify-dandelion.s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/1/6462/user_data_export/1/2023/04/21/15*3A49*3A46-d2a2e810/export.xlsx?response-content-disposition=attachment*3B*20filename*3D*22KHC-*202023*20US*20Retail*20Digital*20Catalog*20Product*20Feed.xlsx*22&response-content-type=application*2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIARRX37GWVL5YUBHGV*2F20230421*2Fus-east-1*2Fs3*2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230421T154946Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=0c22dc1594a61569a00781943113c8a22f4172ae5dbdae210be13edb3b198858__;JSUlJSUlJSUlJSUlJSUlJSUlJQ!!JtwtF54jn92Iq-I!amLXanaK0lF0gjfO4yv1yD4U48nytKnd9NQnISfjc0KKgo0aruIhV0UaABmKNjtGb9vkuqLwhVV52X2Ud5YVFynciVj1kaeI7A$

thanks,

Jeff

Tried coding the Image function as an Array without success
Tried removing the @ sign via excel formatting without success
Worked with Microsoft Premier Support without success
Posted on Microsoft Community Board - some users say that the formula works on their computers.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/image-function-adding-implicit-intersection-at-operator-image/m-p/3790134

Currently using manual work around training

Comment: If I open your file, it behaves as in your video but, when I edit, and say _No_ to the prompt, the formula remains _unchanged_ but the image _does_ appear - if you made a video of this behaviour, showing that the images _can_ appear while the formula remains **exactly** the same, then you can present Microsoft with proof of an actual bug. Btw, a quicker manual workaround is to press CTRL + H, write @ in the _Find what_ field, leave the _Replace with_ field blank (or write another @ there) and then click on _Replace All_ to make all images appear simultaneously.

Comment: SOLVED - formula should be #=_xlfn.image(x,x,x,x,x) - this works for the Caxlsx                                                                                                  
From Microsoft Support -Test Summary:
• Extracted the zip and navigated to Book1.zip\xl\worksheets and opened "sheet1.xml" in notepad++.
• Searched with the keyword "image" - can see string "_xlfn." added before the formula.
•  Same is not being seen on the .xml file of the shared workbook (generated from salisfy).• Please get "_xlfn." string added to the xml before "IMAGE" from salisfy and test the behavior.